# Cucumber detects to many arguments

Tags: java, regex, cucumber, gherkin

I want to detect a list of Apps named `AppA`, `AppB` and `AppC` in my cucumber step.

i.e. `"Given there are 2 badges in the repository owned by AppA,AppB"`

I already tried the following and it works according to the IntelliJ colouring syntax :

```
@Given("^there are (\\d+) badges in the repository owned by (App[ABC](,App[ABC])*)$")
```

But at compilation the following error

```
However, the gherkin step has 3 arguments [2, AppA,AppB, ,AppB].
```

I think it is caused by the parenthesis within the parenthesis of the regex. Does anyone could share me a workaround so I get only `[2, AppA,AppB]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue using the non-capturing groupe `?:`

`@Given("^there are (\\d+) badges in the repository owned by (App[ABC](?:,App[ABC])*)$")`

It seems that cucumber takes everything that is in capturing groups, even if they are nested (even if some regex checker tools only detect 1 for the list)